# How can I clean the list of "Changes to be committed:"?

Tags: git

How can I remove everything in the list of "Changes to be committed", back to the "Changes not staged for commit" state? I essentially want to undo what`git add -A` did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git reset`

You can also selectively reset files with `git reset <file>`